# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TipoDeCanal]',

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, generics

I get this error when passing data from controller to view:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TipoDeCanal]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type TipoDeCanal'.

```
     public class TipoDeCanalesController : GenericController
        {
            private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

            // GET: TipoDeCanales
            public ActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
            {
                //return Json(unitOfWork.TipoDeCanalRepository.Get(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return View(unitOfWork.TipoDeCanalRepository.Get());
            }


@model ..Models.TipoDeCanal
@using ..Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TipoDeCanal>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Nombre).Title("Nombre");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Descripcion).Title("Descripcion");
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "Grid"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Grid"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "Grid"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "Grid"))
    )
)
<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well presumably `unitOfWork.TipoDeCanalRepository.Get()` returns a `List<TipoDeCanal>`... and your view only expects one item. What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view requires single object `@model ...Models.TipoDeCanal` but your controller action obviously return `IEnumerable<TipoDeCanal>`

replace it with `@model List<...Models.TipoDeCanal>`